# Setting Dapr @Topic fields at runtime

Tags: java, docker, jakarta-ee, wildfly, dapr

Stack: Java Jakarta EE10 Wildfly27  Docker Dapr

The issue is configuration of Topics, dynamically.
I have several environments TEST/DEV/PROD and i want to use different topics for the different environments, but the same image. Ideally i would like to set the topic via Environment variables.

So why not do this declarative? Well as i run Dapr on Azure Container Service (ACA) and it does NOT(!) support declarative config(!)

So the way to do this in my subscriber is via the Annotation @Topic

Like this`@Topic(name = "cache_update", pubsubName = "${myAppProperty:messagebus}")`

In the sample above "messagebus" is the default value and "myAppProperty" is the name of the application Property.

Had i used Spring this would have worked but we are using Jakarta EE10 running on Wildfly 27

How on earth can i get this to work?

UPDATE:

Ok, thank You very much for this, however i am still a bit unclear on how to write the Sub part (That will expose a POST endpoint? SO my Endpoint would look something like this instead?

(i.e No @Topic annotation needed?)

```
@Path("/handleTopicRoute")
@RequestScoped 
public class DaprServiceImpl extends AbstractCmsService implements DaprService { 

   public Response receiveMessage(CloudEvent<CacheUpdate> event) { 
   return getResponse(daprSubscriptionController.updateCache(event.getData())); 
}
```

So Dapr finds my mapping endpoint to topic via the endpoint you showed me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dapr Java SDK only provides a native integration for Spring Boot; where Dapr-specific annotations such as `Topic` gets processed and their configuration synthesized into the respective action taking into consideration property resolution, which in your case, would be the topic subscription creation.

To have the a subscription created dynamically toward the config-wired topic values, you can use the Dapr SDK programmatically to create subscription topics by exposing a route over the `/dapr/subscribe` endpoint:

```
@Path("/dapr")
public class DaprController {

   private static final DefaultObjectSerializer SERIALIZER = new DefaultObjectSerializer();

   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Path("/subscribe")
   public Response subscribeTopics() {
       String topic = "TOPIC_NAME"; // you can resolve this value out of environment variables, system properties or MicroProfile config is you are using Wildfly-extras
       String pubsub = "PUBSUB"; // resolve this values as well through any external meaning
       TopicConfig config = new TopicConfig(pubsub, topic, "/handleTopicRoute", Collections.emptyList());
       return Response.ok(SERIALIZER.serialize(Collections.singleton(config))).build();
   }
}
```

Here is the Topic configuration template (Inspired from Spring Boot integration DaprTopicConfiguration):

```
public class TopicConfig {
  private final String pubsubName;
  private final String topic;
  private final String route;
  private final Map<String, String> metadata;

  public TopicConfig(String pubsubName, String topic, String route, Map<String, String> metadata) {
    this.pubsubName = pubsubName;
    this.topic = topic;
    this.route = route;
    this.metadata = Collections.unmodifiableMap(metadata);
  }

  public String getPubsubName() {
    return pubsubName;
  }

  public String getTopic() {
    return topic;
  }

  public String getRoute() {
    return route;
  }

  public Map<String, String> getMetadata() {
    return metadata;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank You very much for this, however i am still a bit unclear on how to write the
Sub part (That will expose a POST endpoint?


SO my Endpoint would look something like this instead?(i.e No @Topic annotation needed?)

`code`

@Path("/handleTopicRoute")
@RequestScoped
public class DaprServiceImpl extends AbstractCmsService implements DaprService {

    public Response receiveMessage(CloudEvent<CacheUpdate> event) {
        return getResponse(daprSubscriptionController.updateCache(event.getData()));
    }

Comment: Would you mind update your main OP with a follow up question as it is hard to read / understand in a comment.

Comment: i did update the OP.

Comment: Exactly, your topic message handler would be statically implemented route as the one you had suggested which Dapr runtime will call with events flowing in the subscribed topic.